# how to freeze header in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Is it possible to freeze the header of a datagridview in a winforms application. The only reference I can find is for web pages.

This does note work:

```
results_grid.Rows(0).Frozen = True
```

Comment: The header is already "frozen".  That is, it doesn't scroll off the view.  Unclear what you are seeing that is different.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to set the grid to the height of the panel that it is in. As the height of the grid grows past the height of the panel, the panel scroll bar becomes visible and then the entire grid scrolls out of view.

Comment: @John did you ever get a solution to this?